# PHP Foreach Empty

Tags: php, foreach

I cant seem to echo the values inside my foreach array, my code so far.

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $item) {

    $imgData = json_decode($item->params, true);
    // create array
    $newsitems[] = array(
        'name' => $item->name,
        'url'  => $item->clickurl,
        'custom'  => $item->custombannercode,
        'image' => $imgData['imageurl']
    );              
}
?>

<?php foreach ($newsitems as $slideitems) {  ?>
  <li> 
     <img src="<?php echo $slideitems->image; ?>" > 
  </li>
<?php }; ?>
```

I get two list items which is correct but when i try to echo out any values it shows blank, am I doing this correct?

Thanks

Comment: `$slideitems` is an array, not an object. Try `echo $slideitems['image']` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($newsitems as $slideitems) {  
  var_dump($slideitems); ?>
  <li> 
     <img src="<?php echo $slideitems['image']; ?>" > 
  </li>
<?php }; ?>
```

You could try a var_dump to see what values you're getting. Also as slideitems is an array check the line that outputs the img src.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just add caffeine and the error will disappear as if by magic :)

Comment: Haha true :) I'm blind without my coffe

Answer (score 2):

```
 $newsitems[] = array( ... )
```

therefore you need

```
<?php echo $slideitems['image']
```

in your ourput loop.

Answer (score 1):

slideitems is not an object, it's an array, `echo $slideitems["image"]`.

Answer (score 1):

`$slideitems` is an `array` not object So,

Change

```
<?php echo $slideitems->image; ?>
```

to

`<?php echo $slideitems['image']; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop you assign array

```
$newsitems[] = array(
```

but here

```
$slideitems->image
```

you're referencing to object. consider using `$slideitems['image']`